# Trouble installing Metagen package for R

Tags: r

I had trouble installing metagen package on R. Can anybody share the versions of R, meta package, and Metagen package that you are using for meta-analysis? Or can anybody let me know any other ways to do meta-analysis of hazard ratios with standard errors?

I used to perform meta-analysis using R 3.6.5 with meta package several years ago. Back then, meta package came with metagen. Recently, I tried to reinstall the same setting, R 3.6.5 with meta package, but I came into too many problems for me to solve. There were too many dependency issues. I think there had been a lot of changes during the past several years. I tried the most recent version of R with meta package, but the most recent meta package does not support Metagen. And I found out metagen package is now removed from CRAN. I somehow installed R 4.0.0 with meta 4.9.5, and metagen 1.0. But I don't like this setting, because funnel plots are somehow misaligned in this setting. I hope there is a good way to substitute my R setting. I wish they reactivate the metagen package.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You should use the newest version of R and the newest versions of all packages. The meta package contains a `metagen` function. If that function does not do what you need, it is unclear what you need.

Comment: Thank you Roland. You are right. I don't know what went wrong before. I think the software got tangled somehow while I tried to install older versions of R, and its packages. Thank you again.